# How to clear and refresh a label in Python's Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, outlook-restapi

I have a program that reads and displays the subject line of Outlook E-mails.  I am wanting it to display the subject in green if the keyword "up" is in the subject.  And red if "down" is in the subject.  Also, when I use an if, elif, else statement, the program doesn't seem to work.  I wanted to use that because I want the program to display red for "down", green for "up", and black/white for any other subjects.

It's sort of working with my code but I cannot figure out how to clear and refresh the label each time a new e-mail subject is read/displayed.

I've tried destory() and os.system('cls') with no luck.

Example:

```
    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetLast()
    body_content = message.Subject 

    if ' up ' in body_content:
        self.answer_label['text'] = os.system('cls')
        self.answer_label['text'] = (body_content) 

    else:
        self.answer_label2['text'] = os.system('cls')
        self.answer_label2['text'] = (body_content)


    self.master.after(20, self.timer)
```

Here is all of my original code:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import tkinter

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class myGUI:

    def timer(self):

        import pythoncom        
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 



        messages = inbox.Items
        message = messages.GetLast()
        body_content = message.Subject 

        if ' up ' in body_content:

            self.answer_label['text'] = (body_content) 

        else:

            self.answer_label2['text'] = (body_content)


        self.master.after(20, self.timer)



    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("CheckStat")


        self.answer_label = Label(master, text='', fg="light green", bg="dark green", font="Helvetica 64 bold italic")
        self.answer_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.answer_label2 = Label(master, text='', fg="red", bg="dark red", font="Helvetica 64 bold italic")
        self.answer_label2.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.timer()


root = Tk()
my_gui = myGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The program does not seem to update with the correct color when I use the "if, elif, else" below.  Any ideas?

```
import win32com.client
import os
import tkinter

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class myGUI:

    def timer(self):

        import pythoncom        
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()  

        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 


        messages = inbox.Items
        message = messages.GetLast()
        body_content = message.Subject 

        if ' up ' in body_content:
            self.answer_labelUp['text'] = (body_content)

        elif ' down ' in body_content:
            self.answer_labelDown['text'] = (body_content)
        else:
            self.answer_labelElse['text'] = (body_content)


        self.master.after(20, self.timer) 



    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("CheckStat")


        self.answer_labelUp = Label(master, text='', fg="light green", bg="dark green", font="Helvetica 64 bold italic")
        self.answer_labelUp.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.answer_labelDown = Label(master, text='', fg="red", bg="dark red", font="Helvetica 64 bold italic")
        self.answer_labelDown.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.answer_labelElse = Label(master, text='', fg="black", bg="white", font="Helvetica 64 bold italic")
        self.answer_labelElse.grid(column=0, row=0) 

        self.timer()


root = Tk()
my_gui = myGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean to use three different `Label`s? Or would you rather use a single `Label` and change the color based on your up/down criteria?

Comment: There are dozens of questions and answers on stackoverflow related to changing the text on a label. I suggest doing a little research before asking such a basic question.